# Find whether a string is palindrome or not.Constrains: No storing the string in any extra variable

Tags: php, algorithm, palindrome

Check the code I have tried

[image]

My question is little bit different than others. I want to make an efficient code for palindrome.So I have added some constrains.Constrains:No storing the string in any extra variable.Use only one loop.I have tried it in php,but it is not rendering the output. I have used the same logic in the image.I am new to php.I need some help to check my code is right,if wrong what changes can be made?No matter whether it is php or any other oops language,I just need to check whether my logic is right.

PHP code:

```
class user{
 public  function __construct(){
   $this->palindrome();

    }

public function palindrome(){
 str ="abba";
 i=0;
 while(str[i] == str[strlen(str-1)-i])
{
i++;
}
  if(i > strlen(str)/2)
 {
 return 0;
  }
   }


   }
  $obj = new user;
```

Comment: Does the solution need to be OO?

Comment: nope.Its fine if its procedural.I will try to convert it to oo afterwards.

Comment: Thanks. In the future try to only use the necessary tags. When you tag a bunch of languages and none are needed, most consider it to be "spamming tags".

Comment: Yes sure :).I will keep that in mind

Comment: Why not just [strrev()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php) the string and compare with the original? No need for an extra variable, no looping at all

Comment: I want it to be dynamic.

Comment: `I want it to be dynamic.` WAT???? Which bit of `return $str === strrev($str);` isn't dynamic?

Comment: Yes we can use strrev().I will use strrev() rather than making my code complicated.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping your logic, corrected the syntax errors.

```
<?php

class user {

    public function __construct() {
        if ($this->palindrome()) {
            echo 'Yes, Palindrome';
        } else {
            echo 'Not a palindrome';
        }
    }

    public function palindrome() {
        //Need $ symbol
        $str = "abba";

        $i = 0;
        //                                 \/
        while ($str[$i] == $str[strlen($str) - ($i + 1)]) {
            $i++;

            if ($i > strlen($str) / 2) {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

}

;

$obj = new user();
```

Comment: It works ,but I am still confused whether all my constrains are satisfied.

Comment: I think your logic use only one loop and only one variable for storing string. so it might be.

Answer (score 0):

A few minor mistakes:

`str[strlen(str-1)-i]` => `str[strlen(str)-1-i])`
And you don't terminate the loop when the check is complete.
You could move the if-statement into the loop and return true.
Or use a for loop 0 -> length/2 and return false if characters are not equal.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the structure but maintained your logic.

```
<?php

class User {
    private $str;

    public function __construct($str) {
        $this->str = $str;
    }

    public function palindrome() {
        $i = 0;
        while ($this->str[$i] == $this->str[strlen($this->str) - ($i + 1)]) {
            $i++;

            if ($i > strlen($this->str) / 2) {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

}

$obj = new User("abba");

echo $obj->palindrome(); // can be zero or one
```